# How to separate a string by more than one character in lua?

Tags: string, lua

string is "abc||d|ef||ghi||jkl",
How to divide this string into an array, if the separator is "||" .
eg. "abc","d|ef","ght","jkl".

### I found a code to split a string, but only one character can be used as a separator.
the code is :

```lua
text={}
string="abc||d|ef||ghi||jkl"

for w in string:gmatch("([^|]*)|")
do 
  table.insert(text,w) 
end

for i=1,4
do
   print(text[i])
end
```

---

Therefore, how to seperate the string with multiple characters?

Answer (score 0):

Well, either grab letters `'[a-zA-Z]+'` -or- `'[%a]+'` your choice.

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua
text = {}
string = 'abc||def||ghi||jkl'

for w in string :gmatch( '[a-zA-Z]+' ) do 
    table .insert( text, w ) 
end

for i = 1, #text do
    print( text[i] )
end
```

or anything that isn't pipes `'[^|]+'`

```
text = {}
string = 'abc||def||ghi||jkl'

for w in string :gmatch( '[^|]+' ) do 
    table .insert( text, w ) 
end

for i = 1, #text do
    print( text[i] )
end
```

https://riptutorial.com/lua/example/20315/lua-pattern-matching

> abc
> def
> ghi
> jkl

Comment: If  the string = 'abc||d|ef||ghi||jkl',  it can not be seperate to "abc";"d|ef";“ghi”;"jkl".

Comment: That's not what you asked.  `string is "abc||def||ghi||jkl"` ...

Comment: Thank you.I didn't make it clear. What I mean is that there are only two consecutive "||" characters as separators, and the separated string should be between two groups of  "||" .

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
text={}
string="abc||def||ghi||jkl"

for w in string:gmatch("([^|]*)||")
do 
  table.insert(text,w) 
end

for i=1,4
do
   print(text[i])
end
```

It's the same code, just with another "|".

EDIT:

This should work better now:

```
str = "abc||d|ef||ghi||jkl"

function getMatches(inputString)
    
    hits = {}
    
    beginSection = 1
    
    consecutive = 0
    
    for index=0,#inputString do
        chr = string.sub(inputString,index,index)
        if chr=="|" then
            consecutive = consecutive+1
            if consecutive >= 2 then
                consecutive = 0
                table.insert(hits,string.sub(inputString,beginSection,index-2))
                beginSection = index + 1
            end
        else
            consecutive = 0
        end
    end
    
    if beginSection ~= #inputString then
        table.insert(hits,string.sub(inputString,beginSection,#inputString))
    end
    
    return hits
end

for _,v in pairs(getMatches(str)) do print(v) end

io.read()
```

Patterns aren't always the way to go in Lua, they are rather limited (no grouping).

Comment: I am sorry, I edited my question, if the string is "abc||d|ef||ghi||jkl",  the code is not working correctly.

Comment: @fayehoo Is that better?